# Can I use fetch_array() twice inside a single php block?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$idno = $_GET['id'];
$identity = $idno;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bloggings WHERE id ='$idno'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    ...
}

$resu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE id='$identity'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resu))
{
    ...
}
```

I got error like this type:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\AlumniAssociation\blog_written.php on
>   line 95

Comment: Can you show us what code is inside the loops? Perhaps you are using $row or $resu inside the loop and it's overwritten?

Comment: That should'nt be a problem, the problem is that the query probably returned an error, and you have no error handling. As a sidenote you should be using PDO or mysqli.

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing raw, unfiltered, unvalidated user input directly into an SQL string. Please [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 2):

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

This error means that your query failed for some reason. On failure, [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns `false`. It is usually due to a syntax error, missing field/table or no connection to the database.

You should test for the query failing so that you never pass a boolean to `mysql_fetch_array()`:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bloggings WHERE id ='$idno'");

if($result)
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        ...
    }
}
else
{
    // query failed - see mysql_error()
}
```

There is no problem with having multiple `fetch_*` calls on the same page, as long as you are using different result resources (otherwise it will move the pointer forward each time).

Side note: `mysql_*` is deprecated, it is recommended to upgrade to MySQLi or PDO. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, use a parameterised query instead of manually interpolating variables into the query.

Answer (score 0):

Check the database conection and then mysql error.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bloggings WHERE id ='$idno'");
if (!$result) { // add this check.
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create database connection? if yes check the connection. and try to run the `mysql_query()` only if the connection returns true.